# Intersection of ordinary subspaces at different primes

Tags: modular-forms, hida-theory

Choose two distinct primes $\ell$ and $\ell'$, and embeddings $\iota_\ell : \overline{\mathbb Q} \to \overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$, $\iota_{\ell'} : \overline{\mathbb Q} \to \overline{\mathbb Q_{\ell'}}$.

Let $M_k = M_k(\ell \ell', \overline{\mathbb Q})$ be the space of weight $k$ modular forms of level $\Gamma_0(\ell\ell')$ and $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ coefficients.

Hida has defined the ordinary projector $e_{\text{ord}, \ell} = \varinjlim_{n\to \infty} (U_\ell)^{n!}$ on $M_k \otimes_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$, and $e_{\text{ord}, \ell'}$ on $M_k \otimes_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}\overline{\mathbb Q_{\ell'}}$.

Let

$$M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell} = e_{\text{ord}, \ell}(M_k \otimes_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell})$$
$$M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell'} = e_{\text{ord}, \ell'}(M_k \otimes_{\overline{\mathbb Q}}\overline{\mathbb Q_{\ell'}}).$$

Hida shows that the dimension of $M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell}$ over $\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$ is idependent of $k$. Similarily, the dimension of $M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell'}$ is independent of $k$.

Let

$$\mathcal M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell} = M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell} \cap M_k$$
and
$$\mathcal M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell'} = M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell'} \cap M_k.$$

What, if anything, is known about the dimension over $\overline{\mathbb Q}$ of $\mathcal M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell} \cap \mathcal M_k^{\text{ord}, \ell'}$?
 It is of course bounded as a function of $k$. Can one say anything more? Does it eventually stabilize?